# why doesn't Series.dtype return a type of datetime

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

[image]

I had a variable tradeDate 。the type of it's value is datetime.however ,when i  run tradeDate.dtype ,it gives me Out[12]: dtype('O')  ,why not datetime. or how do i know if the type of it's value is datetime

i will show how do i get tradeDate  data

[[image]

there is a excel file,and i read it as below

```
df_tradeDate = pandas.read_excel('E:/dataCenter/TradeDates.xlsx')
```

and then ,i convert the data into datetime as below

```
df_tradeDate['date']=pandas.to_datetime(df_tradeDate['date'],format='%Y%m%d',errors='coerce')
```

at last .I get the  tradeDate

```
tradeDate=df_tradeDate['date'].dt.date
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtMoU.png)

Comment: Are there mixed datatypes in there?

Comment: @bernie no ,it's not . some data was showed on the picture.

Comment: How do you know that "the type of its value is datetime"?  What makes you think it is?

Comment: Can you post an example of your data? I find this question unclear...

Comment: @ Alex Petralia  i have already upload the data ,woud you help seeing the problem again

Comment: @ BrenBarn  i have showed how the tradeDate value come,woud you help solving the problem again

Answer (score 1):

Pandas uses numpy's datetime dtypes called [`datetime64`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) which is different from the datetime types in python's standard library module [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime).

When you are accessing `df_tradeDate['date'].dt.date`, pandas returns a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) object back which is a generic object in pandas world. Hence you see the dtype difference.

Note that while numpy has units such as `datetime64[D]` to represent dates, pandas converts all such units to nanoseconds. Hence the only posible datetime dtype in pandas is `datetime64[ns]`. This does not really lead to any issues in practice.

Comment: sorry ,i  can't  understand what the last sentence mean